# Apache Shiro with AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, apache, spring-mvc, shiro

I am new with AngularJS when I am creating AngularJS project setup with apache shiro configuration there is a problem with login page its not redirecting properly in shiroFilter could any one help me or any one have sample project by using `Apache Shiro with AngularJS`

Comment: Can you update the question with a copy of your web.xml file and shiro.ini file please?

Comment: I am getting same error..I am using https://github.com/gnavarro77/angular-shiro